# Using jquery load() to include php page that submits a html table back to the main page

Tags: php, html, jquery

I load foo.php into index.php. foo.php has a form that I submit to get a table of results. If I use php 'include' I can submit and get results back but if I use jquery load() I don't see the results.

This works:

```
  <div class='loaded' id="foo_loaded">
  <?php include('foo.php'); ?>
  </div>
```

This doesn't:

```
$("#foo_loaded").load('foo.php');
```

In both situations the original html before I submit will show. When I submit though only the one method will generate the table.

I'd prefer to use jquery for the faster loads and because when using php 'include' the pages which get loaded as a hidden div don't get hidden until after everything loads which isn't pleasing to the eye.

For example. With the following code I want to load home if the form hasn't been submitted, but if submitted I want it to hide home and show foo. Instead if I'm using php 'include', home first loads and then hides after the page is finished.

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo '$(".loaded").hide();';
        echo '$("#foo_loaded").show();';
  }
  else {

   echo '$(".loaded").hide();';
   echo '$("#home_loaded").show();';
  }
?>
```

Comment: Does foo.php rely on the parent PHP to supply any specific variables? For example, can you load foo.php on it's own?

Comment: @Twisty - Yes and that's how it was previously. I'm trying to create a single load page where menu locations are preloaded into the main page.

Comment: You'll have to ensure that foo.php output clean HTML or can be stand alone so that it can be called via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using iframes.

The problem I was having with divs not hiding while the page loads was fixed by adding 'display:none' css in the style tag of the page rather than trying to work it with jquery.